# SQL: Specify Which Table A Column Name Is Referring To

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am selecting data from the same table in one SQL query and need to **specify which table the particular column I am using refers to**.

***BASICALLY: x is ambiguous and I need to make it non-ambiguous.***

*For example I have...*

```
     SELECT DISTINCT x,
     (SELECT x FROM Y WHERE x=x)
     FROM Y                 ^ ^
                            | |
                            | |_ [x referring to outer select statement]
    [x referring to inner] _| 
    [  select statement  ]
```

I need to somehow specify that the **x on the right** hand side is referring to the current value of x from the **outer select statement**. Currently, it believes that it is referring to itself so it always returns true.

Comment: I hope that query is not real.

Comment: No its not. The inner statement is an ultra simplified version of something that is syntactically valid. The inner select statement gets the idea across though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use table aliases:

```
SELECT DISTINCT h.x,
     (SELECT x FROM Y as g WHERE g.x=h.x)
     FROM Y as h
```

This way you can create temp table names and point to them, especially helpful for self-joins

Can we with or without 'AS' in Sql server:

```
table_name AS table alias
table_name table_alias
```

[More info](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Don't you need to add the word "as"? So it would be "FROM Y as h"

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT yOut.x,
 (SELECT yIN.x FROM Y as yIN WHERE yIN.x=yOut.x) as someColName
 FROM Y as yOut                      ^    ^
                                     |    |
                                     |    |_ [x referring to outer select statement]
[is your table alias ] ______________| 
[from inner select]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use aliases for your tables to make it very clear.